# Tslint always enforcing no-submodule-imports rule even if disabled

Tags: typescript, parse-server, tslint

I'm trying to configure my tslint to allow submodules from the `Parse` library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-js) so I can use `parse/react-native`, but it doesn't work.

I have tried to do add both `"no-submodule-imports": [true, "parse", "parse/react-native"]`and `"no-submodule-imports": false` in my tslint but I still get the following error:

```
ERROR: src/App.tsx:2:19 - Submodule import paths from this package are disallowed; import from the root instead
```

The declaration in `@types/parse` for this submodule in node_modules is:

```
declare module "parse/node" {
    export = Parse;
}

declare module "parse" {
    import * as parse from "parse/node";
    export = parse
}

declare module "parse/react-native" {
    import * as parse from "parse/node";
    export = parse
}
```

The code does work fine, but if I run tslint I get that error. I tried different combinations of it and still have the issue.

Here's what my tslint.json looks like:

```
{
  "extends": [
    "tslint:latest",
    "tslint-react",
    "tslint-react-a11y",
    "tslint-config-prettier"
  ],
  "no-submodule-imports": [true, "parse", "parse/react-native"],
  "import-blacklist": false,
  "defaultSeverity": "error",
  "rules": {
    "ban": {
      "options": [
        ["_", "extend", "use object spread: { ...a, ...b }"],
        ["_", "isNull", "use plain JS: == null"],
        ["_", "isDefined", "use plain JS: != null"],
        ["Object", "assign", "use object spread: { ...a, ...b }"],
        ["Object", "getOwnPropertyNames", "use Object.keys()"],
        ["describe", "only", "should not be committed to repo"],
        ["it", "only", "should not be committed to repo"],
        ["test", "only", "should not be committed to repo"]
      ]
    },
    "no-object-literal-type-assertion": false,
    "ordered-imports": [
      true,
      {
        "import-sources-order": "any",
        "named-imports-order": "any"
      }
    ],
    "no-any": true,
    "interface-over-type-literal": false,
    "linebreak-style": {
      "options": ["LF"]
    },
    "quotemark": [true, "single"],
    "jsx-boolean-value": ["never"],
    "member-access": [true],
    "no-console": false,
    "no-implicit-dependencies": false,
    "no-invalid-this": {
      "options": ["check-function-in-method"]
    },
    "interface-name": false,
    "max-classes-per-file": false,
    "jsx-no-lambda": false,
    "no-trailing-whitespace": true,
    "no-this-assignment": [
      true,
      {
        "allow-destructuring": true
      }
    ],
    "no-unnecessary-callback-wrapper": false,
    "no-unnecessary-initializer": true,
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false,
    "prefer-conditional-expression": false,
    "variable-name": {
      "options": [
        "allow-leading-underscore",
        "allow-pascal-case",
        "ban-keywords",
        "check-format"
      ]
    },
    "member-ordering": [
      true,
      "private-before-public",
      "static-before-instance",
      "variables-before-functions"
    ],
    "trailing-comma": [
      true,
      {
        "multiline": "always",
        "singleline": "never",
        "esSpecCompliant": true
      }
    ]
  },
  "jsRules": {
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false
  },
  "linterOptions": {
    "exclude": [
      "/**/packages/newrelic-webpack-plugin/embedded.js",
      "/**/coverage/**/*",
      "/**/*.json",
      "/**/build/**/*"
    ]
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: How are you running TSLint?

Comment: Hi Josh, I have this in my package.json: ` "lint": "tslint 'src/**/*.{ts,tsx}' -c ./tslint.json"`
But vscode also complains about it. The tslint.json is in the root of the project.

Comment: I have same problem using Jetbrains WebStorm integration with tslint, still no idea if it's bug.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this also. It looks like for an angular project the rule needs to be in the tslint file inside of the src folder.